# How can I read in my C# app-1 the standard console output of a C# app-2 consol app live during a timespan?

Tags: c#, console-application

Currently ,in my C# app-1, I can read the standard console output of a C# console app (app-2) once, when the console app exits. This works fine.

But in my new use case the console app (app-2) will generate cyclic some values (every 1 second, for totally 20 seconds). I want to read these values from my app-1, as soon as they have been generated. That means in my app-1 I should be able to see the value changes "live" for the given timespan. With live I don't mean realtime, some delay is acceptable.

My current app-1:

```
         public void Read_Std_Output_app2()
         {
            Process_app2 = new Process                
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = app2_path,
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            Process_app2.Start();
            item_value = Process_app2.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Process_app2.WaitForExit();
         }
```

My current app-2: (generating output once)

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          // code for generating output
          Console.WriteLine(item_value_output)
          Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

My app-2 with cycling value generating: (new use case)

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
           while(var_true)
           {
             // code for generating cyclic output
             Console.Clear()
             Console.WriteLine(item_value_output)
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
           }
        }
```

Comment: If you start both processes in your program you can copy the `StandardOutput` stream of the first process to `StandardInput` of the second process with `p1.StandardOutput.CopyTo(p2.StandardInput)`. You'll have to do that in a separate thread to avoid blocking your program. If you use a shell like PowerShell or CMD, the shell can do it for you. You can host PowerShell in your application and construct more complex pipelines than this

Comment: Do you have to use separate processes? You could use TransformBlock and ActionBlock to construct pipelines of processing blocks in your own application, each using its own worker tasks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Unfortunately I have to use two different apps. Reason is that I have to read data from remote OPC DA servers. Reading from OPC DA server is legacy method and needs some special DCOM security setting modifications. My main app is a web app managed with ISS, where I cannot do this settings. So I can make it just when I use a .NET console app for it.

Comment: In that case you have either use `Stream.Copy` to copy from one process to another or use a PowerShell script. That's essentially the same as writing `p1 | p2` in a shell.  If the streams need special processing (eg detecting start/stop message boundaries)`, you'll have to read from `p1.StandardOutput`, parse the message and if appropriate, write it to `p2.StandardInput`. Another tricky issue is that the processes will start using the web app's app pool account. Are you sure they'll work? Perhaps you should start with a Powershell script to see what works before writing C# code

Comment: You can use anonymous pipes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication

Comment: You just had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77933148/982149) about OPC-DA access. Is _that_ the "legacy method"? I mean you could totally change all of it to create a _service_ that subscribes to OPC DA and writes changes / data to whatever you like: Database, distributed Cache, MessageQueue, LogFile, ...