# Is it possible to read the standard output of a console app, before the console app exits? I mean without using Process.WaitForExit()?

Tags: c#, console-output

I have C# app1 that starts the C# console app2 and reads the console standard output values of it. Normally I am reading the outputs with code below (app1)

```
    public void read_values_from_app2
    {    
       Process_OPCDA = new Process                
       {
           StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
           {
               FileName = MTX_OPC_DA_reader_path,
               Arguments = arguments,
               UseShellExecute = false,
               RedirectStandardOutput = true,
               CreateNoWindow = true
           }
       };
       Process_OPCDA.Start();
       string item_values = Process_OPCDA.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       Process_OPCDA.WaitForExit();                     
     }
```

This is working but I am reading the outputs with 4-5 seconds delay because the console app (app-2) connects first to remote CNC machine, reads the required values, disconnects and then exits.
Here the disconnect step takes up to 4-5 seconds. So although the values are there I have to wait additionally 4-5 seconds until I get the values in my app-1, because of the Process_OPCDA.WaitForExit() command in my app-1.

Is there a way to get the console output, as soon as the output is written without waiting the console app to exit?

My console app looks like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // Connecting to a remote maachine
      // Reading values from it
      Console.WriteLine(values);
      // Disconnecting from the machine (takes 4-5 seconds)
      Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

When I cancell the line Process_OPCDA.WaitForExit() in my app-1 code I cannot read anything. So how should revise my code in app-1?

Comment: You asked exactly the same question a couple of days ago here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939405/how-can-i-read-in-my-c-sharp-app-1-the-standard-console-output-of-a-c-sharp-app.  But you didn't make your restrictions and exact requirements clear and just rejected everybodies proposal.

Comment: See the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39624153/2791540) for some code that could work for you.

Comment: Don't use `ReadToEnd()`. Read the output line by line until the main app has all the expected data. Instead of calling `WaitForExit()` just continue with other work in your main app. If possible flush the output stream in your secondary app before disconnecting. Depending on the values you are reading the secondary app might have to print a special line to mark the end of the values for the main app.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride  Thank you so much, this was the solution for me. Easier as expected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by calling a DLL in your writing program and inject your reading program into it / creating the reading program as a DLL

Comment: There are some security related settings, that I cannot change in the main app, so therefore had to split the function to another app (app2)